# How to display files in listview in one line in C# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to display files and it's size in a listview and it should show like it's in 2 columns.. but somehow it shows like this.. [image]

here's my code :

```
    private void btnScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = cmbDrive.Text;
        string extension1 = "*.png";
        string extension2 = "*.doc";
        string extension3 = "*.txt";

        foreach (string s in FileUts.GetFiles(path, extension1).Union(FileUts.GetFiles(path, extension2)).Union(FileUts.GetFiles(path, extension3)))
        {

            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(s);
            lvDBview.Items.Add(s);
            lvDBview.Items.Add(BytesToString(file.Length));

         }
```

Comment: [ListView.View Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Unrelated, consider using an array (or some other enumerable) for your extensions `string[] extensions = { "*.png", "*.doc", "*.txt" }` and then changing your `foreach` to `foreach (string s in extensions.SelectMany(ext => FileUts.GetFiles(path, ext)))` for reasons of scalability and ease of maintenance.

Comment: `lvDBview.View = View.Details`

Answer (score 6):

You need to set [`ListView.View`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `List`:

```
lvDBview.View = View.List;
```

For more options visit [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/listview).